# Redirect from servlet to JSP not working

Tags: jsp, redirect, servlets

My following code to redirect from servlet to jsp is not working, where redirect to html is working. Both html & jsp are in the same folder. I have tried all the solutions given in the stackoverflow, but not working ie blank page is displayed.

```
        if (user.toUpperCase().equals("IMS")){
            //Not working
            response.sendRedirect("/SecondServletProject/Hello.jsp");
            }
        else{
            //Working
            response.sendRedirect("LoginFailed.html");
        }
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem. What exactly happens? What exactly happens not? Try to describe the problem as a developer. "not working" is what an ignorant enduser would say. Do you get a HTTP 404 "Page not found" error? Do you get an exception? Did the webbrowser crash? Press F12 in webbrowser and view page source to find clues.

Comment: Use RequestDispathcher  


RequestDispatcher rd=servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/pathToResource");
  rd.forward(request, response);

Comment: Balus, Thanks for your response, I have clearly mentioned "blank page is displayed".

Comment: Gladiator, thanks, but not working.

Comment: What is the project folder structure?? If the jsp is under webapp folder then u should write Hello.jsp

Comment: Press F12 in webbrowser (Network/Console especially) and view page source to find clues.

Comment: Folder structure is as follows

SecondServletProject >> WebContent >> Hello.jsp, Index.html

Comment: Balus, following is the view page source

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>

Answer (score 0):

If they are in the same folder, and the second one works, change:

```
response.sendRedirect("/SecondServletProject/Hello.jsp");
```

to:

```
response.sendRedirect("Hello.jsp");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is not working. I have deployed the application in tomcat, but same problem. Any more ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure about the name of the file? Lower case and upper case?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about the name of the file.

Comment: So, the web server is not well configured. It serves plain html files, but unable to interpret JSP pages.

Comment: Wabbi, Thanks, but I have deployed pure JSP application on the same server, it is working fine. The problem is wth servlet to JSP redirect.

Comment: When you type the URL of the JSP page `Hello.jsp` directly in the URL text field of the browser, does it show correctly? Anyway, I don't agree that there is something special about redirecting from a servlet to a JSP page.